# Cypher query returns nothing but data is there

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given this graph:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/g3j3xo

I am trying to return all philosophers who influence philosophers within the same schoolTypeClass.  First I will show queries that are working fine.  The problem query is at the bottom of the post.

This is the query that is the default in the link above.  I is intended to demonstrate that the data is there.  That is, both Aristotle and Plato share SchoolTypeClass 'movement'

```
MATCH p1:Philosopher-[:MEMBER_OF]->s1:School-[:TYPE_OF]->st1:SchoolType-[:SUBCLASS_OF]->stc1:SchoolTypeClass
   WHERE  stc1.name = 'movement'
   RETURN p1.name as p1Name, s1.name as s1Name, st1.name as st1Name, stc1.name as stc1Name
```

This is a query that works fine.  It is very similar to the query that does not work.  It shows philosophers who influence philosophers within the same schoolType rather than schoolTypeClass

```
MATCH st2:SchoolType<-[:TYPE_OF]-s2:School<-[:MEMBER_OF]-p2:Philosopher<-[:INFLUENCES]-p1:Philosopher-[:MEMBER_OF]->s1:School-[:TYPE_OF]->st1:SchoolType
   WHERE  st2 = st1
   RETURN p1.name as p1Name, s1.name as s1Name, st1.name as st1Name, p2.name as p2Name, s2.name as s2Name, st2.name as st2Name
```

Problem Query returns nothing.  How to get philosophers who influence philosophers within the same schoolTypeClass?

```
MATCH stc2:SchoolTypeClass<-[:SUBCLASS_OF]-st2:SchoolType<-[:TYPE_OF]-s2:School<-[:MEMBER_OF]-p2:Philosopher<-[:INFLUENCES]-p1:Philosopher-[:MEMBER_OF]->s1:School-[:TYPE_OF]->st1:SchoolType-[:SUBCLASS_OF]->stc1:SchoolTypeClass
   WHERE stc1 = stc2
   RETURN p1.name as p1Name, s1.name as s1Name, st1.name as st1Name, stc1.name as stc1Name, p2.name as p2Name, s2.name as s2Name, st2.name as st2Name, stc2.name as stc2Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the same node twice with different names in the same MATCH (stc1/2).

```
MATCH p=s2:School<-[:MEMBER_OF]-p2:Philosopher
        <-[:INFLUENCES]-p1:Philosopher-[:MEMBER_OF]->s1:School
        -[:TYPE_OF]->st1:SchoolType-[:SUBCLASS_OF]->stc:SchoolTypeClass 
WHERE (stc)<-[:SUBCLASS_OF]-(:SchoolType)<-[:TYPE_OF]-s2 
RETURN p1.name AS p1Name, s1.name AS s1Name, st1.name AS st1Name, 
       stc.name AS stcName, p2.name AS p2Name, s2.name AS s2Name, p
```

So you rather check after the match.

http://console.neo4j.org/r/t6lj05

Comment: I am marking this as the answer since it returns the correct result.  However, it is not true that you "cannot have the same node twice with different names in the same MATCH."  I am doing this in the second query of my post where I test for node equality with WHERE st2=st1.